# R convert nested for loop to lapply() for better performance

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, nested-loops

I am having difficulties converting my nested `for` loop to `lapply()` for speed reasons.

I have 2 `data.table`s that I am looping over every single row in order to compare it's contents and if equal, do some calculations. It's taking me more than 10 min to do the calculations for my dataset of about 1000 rows and 360 rows.

In this minimal example, it's less than a second, but it's only 3 rows each:

```
library(data.table)
library(tictoc)

name <- c(rep("apple",2), rep("banana",2), rep("citrus", 2))
stim <- c("nc","alk" ,"nc",  "lem", "haz", "nc")
vis <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 7)
f <-c(2,2,2,1,3,3)
g <-c(2,2,2,2,4,4)
h <- c(rep(2,6))
value<- c(5,10,5,10,10,5)
  
tab <- data.table(name, stim, vis, f,g,h,value)

tab1 <- tab[stim == "nc"]
tab2 <- tab[!(stim == "nc")]


tic("looping")

for(i in 1:NROW(tab1)){
  for (n in 1: NROW((tab2))){
    if(identical(tab2[n,name],tab1[i,name])
       
    & identical(tab2[n,vis],tab1[i,vis])
      & identical(tab2[n,3:(length(tab2)-1), with = FALSE],tab1[i,3:(length(tab1)-1), with = FALSE])){
       
      tab2[n,"value"] <- tab2[n, "value"] - tab1[i,"value"]
    }  
  }
  
}
toc()
```

I've been looking at the `apply` family and it seems to be one way to go but I cannot figure out how to solve it. I appreciate any help!

Edit:
Before looping, `tab1` looks like this:

```
     name stim vis f g h value
1:  apple   nc   1 2 2 2     5
2: banana   nc   1 2 2 2     5
3: citrus   nc   7 3 4 2     5
```

`tab2` looks like this:

```
     name stim vis f g h value
1:  apple  alk   1 2 2 2    10
2: banana  lem   1 1 2 2    10
3: citrus  haz   6 3 4 2    10
```

After looping (only interested in `tab2`), expected result:

```
     name stim vis f g h value
1:  apple  alk   1 2 2 2     5
2: banana  lem   1 1 2 2    10
3: citrus  haz   6 3 4 2    10
```

Comment: can you explain the condition used?

Comment: eg if I want to cbind every row of  `tab1` with the whole of `tab2` then I would do something like: `Map(function(x,y)cbind(x[rep(1,nrow(y))],y),split(tab1,1:3),list(tab2))`. Therefore you need to define what you need to do for `tab1` and `tab2` where there is the `cbind` function

Comment: I don't wnat to cbind anything. I am checking if certain columns of each row of two different data.tables are identical, and only if yes, do some calculations on these two rows.

Comment: I was just giving an example with cbind..

Comment: sorry. I missunderstood. I will try your approach and get back

Comment: would you mind adding the results you expect?

Comment: I added the results. The condition: certain column values of compared rows need to be the same in order to be subtracted. Is that helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A apply loop will not speed up your computation.  In fact it *WILL* make it slower, since you already have your data.frames defined and you are just replacing values.

Instead, I suggest an alternate approach using merge.  (Note: your code had some errors and did not run, so I hope I am interpreting your intentions correctly.  If not, let me know).

```
> merge(tab1, tab2, by = c("name", "vis", "f", "g", "h"), suffixes=c("1", "2"), all.y=T) -> tab3
> tab3$value <- tab3$value2-tab3$value1
> tab3
    name vis f g h stim1 value1 stim2 value2 value
1  apple   1 2 2 2    nc      5   alk     10     5
2 banana   1 1 2 2  <NA>     NA   lem     10    NA
3 citrus   6 3 4 2  <NA>     NA   haz     10    NA
```

From there you can rename or move your columns as you like.

Comment: error came from missing libraries. Sorry about that beginner mistake. I tried your approach and it's working fantastic. I got my time down to less than 1 sec!

Comment: as this was a minimal example I am now dealing with multiple columns that need to be subtracted,e.g. : col 2- col 5, col3-col6 for multiple pairs of columns. I was trying something like: tab3[,3:5] = tab3[,3:5] - tab3[,7:9] but cannot get it work, due to wrong syntax.

Comment: You can subtract columns by indexing or by negative indexing.  E.g.: `tab3 <- tab3[,c(-2,-3)]` will subtract columns 2 and 3.